# Looking for a phrase: a needlessly overcomplicated method of accomplishing a simple task

Tags: phrases, idioms, popular-refrains

In my language, there is an expression for this - you can touch the tip of your nose normally, or you can move your hand behind your neck, across it, then touch the tip of the nose from the opposite side. I can't translate this to a concise and acceptable phrase/idiom, and the descriptive version loses its sheen in the verbose explanation.

So what's a good phrase in English for this? I've heard of some close versions like:

- three right turns to make a left
- two steps forward, one step back (although this is usually in the context of progress)

But they don't quite get the same feeling across.

Comment: "Three right turns to make a left" is a good one. "He has to call out the Armed Forces to wipe his ass," is another.

Comment: The toilet paper is milspec.

Comment: _Rigamarole_ is a fine word with this meaning.

Comment: kludgy, from kludge:  "1. A system, especially a computer system, that is constituted of poorly matched elements or of elements originally intended for other applications.

2.  A clumsy or inelegant solution to a problem."  http://www.thefreedictionary.com/kludgy

Answer (score 2):

In the USA they call such a person a "Rube Goldberg" after the cartoonist who depicted highly complicated devices for doing simple tasks.

"You are turning that task into a real Rube Goldberg machine."

*Oxford Dictionaries Online* defines *[Rube Goldberg [machine]](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/Rube-Goldberg)* as

> Ingeniously or unnecessarily complicated in design or construction

In the UK we had Heath Robinson, a cartoonist who drew similar machines, but who predates Goldberg.

"That's a bit of a Heath Robinson contraption you've made of that job!"

Comment: Beg to differ... "Rube Goldberg" is more commonly used to denote the mechanism (or, process) rather than the person employing it. (US) In *that* sense, it's a good answer.

Comment: Not true. The phrase in the US always includes "machine" as in "Rube Goldberg machine." A person is likened to Rube Goldberg if they make such a system. From Wikipedia: "Over the years, the expression has expanded to mean any confusing or complicated system. For example, news headlines include "Is Rep. Bill Thomas the Rube Goldberg of Legislative Reform?" and "Retirement 'insurance' as a Rube Goldberg machine"."

Comment: Perhaps you are correct about the word "machine" being added now. Maybe because the expression "Rube Goldberg" is not as well known (or commonly used) as it was years ago. P.S. Never say "always".

Comment: That could also be *a Rube Goldberg **device*** — and often enough is.

Comment: @tchrist: citation please. I have never heard such a usage. "Rube Goldberg Machine" is canonical. Search for "Rube Goldberg device" and you will find that the results all refer to "Rube Goldberg machine."

Comment: @ChannelIslander [Your requested citation](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/RubeGoldbergDevice).

Comment: @tchrist: Really? TVtropes.org ? C'mon.

Comment: +1 Added citation and definition. Please feel free to delete if you disagree.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Channel Islander.

Another UK possibility is "to over egg the pudding".

> over-egg the pudding   (British) to spoil something by trying too hard
>   to improve it As a director, I think he has a tendency to over-egg the
>   pudding, with a few too many gorgeous shots of the countryside.
>
> [thefreedictionary.com](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/over-egg+the+pudding)